# shows input text when add item in dropdown is clicked

Tags: php, jscript

I have a dropdown where the values are fetched from the database,
[image]

now, when the last option which is the " ADD ELEMENTARY SCHOOL" is selected, I want the dropdown to be hidden and an input text will **replace** the dropdown that will let the user enter a not existing data like this one. Thanks

[image]

This is my html code.

```html
<select id="elemschool" class="form-control">
<?php
  $select=$dbcon->query("Select * from elem_school");
      while ($row=$select->fetch_array()) {
        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $row['Elem_ID']?>">
                          <?php echo $row['School_Name']?>
                        </option>
    <?php
       }
  ?>
        <option style="background-color: #77A5F8" class="addelem" value="addelementary">- ADD ELEMENTARY SCHOOL -</option>
    
</select>

<input type="text" class="form-control hidden" name="elem_school" id="elem_school" placeholder="NAME OF SCHOOL">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all please provide us with a snippet of the existing code so we can change it to a working one and secondly what if someone want to select the

> MANAOLO FORTICH CENTRAL ELEMENTARY SCHOOL

and selected the

> ADD ELEMENTARY SCHOOL option

how would you allow the user to select another option if its not there

What I would recommend is to show/hide or disable/enable the input box depending on what user select from the list

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <select name='school' onchange="newSchool(this.value)">
  <option value="">Select a school</option>
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
  <input type="text" id="input" disabled />

  <script>
    function newSchool(schoolName) {
      if (schoolName == 3) {
        document.getElementById("input").disabled = false;
      } else {
        document.getElementById("input").disabled = true;
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

If you want to hide it as well as disabling it

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <select name='school' onchange="newSchool(this.value)">
  <option value="">Select a school</option>
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
  <input type="text" id="input" disabled />

  <script>
    document.getElementById("input").hidden = true;

    function newSchool(schoolName) {
      if (schoolName == 3) {
        document.getElementById("input").hidden = false;
        document.getElementById("input").disabled = false;
      } else {
        document.getElementById("input").hidden = true;
        document.getElementById("input").disabled = true;
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

prepare two DOM element. A visible select element and a hidden input element.
bind a change event to select element, and check if the value equal to the value of item named "add elementary school", and then hidden the select element and show the input element.